# What did Oliver Queen say to the Russian guard in S02E06?

Tags: dialogue, arrowverse, arrow, translation

In the most recent episode of Arrow (season 2, episode 6), what did Oliver Queen say to the Russian guard (in Russian)? The scene is about 18 minutes into the episode.

Comment: is it available for streaming? I'd like to see it and try my hand at translating.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"If you do this, my people will make your children orphans"

Speaking of style, huh :))

Answer (score 4):

It's something like: "If you won't let us go, my people will find you and your children"
The rest I couldn't understand because of his accent...

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on Russian but I'm pretty sure he said: "If you shoot us, my men will slaughter you (as a group), and give your kids to poor people."